# Different Particles Editor for LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, game-engine, particle-system

I'm a newbie in 2d game programming. I currently use for my project libgdx framework. I want create particles effect but the particle editor that came with library is not very easy for me. Is there a possibility to use different program to create particles and use with libgdx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now this is the only [Particle Editor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Particle-editor) with support for Libgdx. You may use another one. But you would need to write a loader for it. Which is much harder than learning how to use the Libgdx one.

I advice you to take some time to learn it. Its worth it.